# Using BOOST_PP_FOR_EACH for a list of compound elements

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

Is it possible to use the [Boost preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to convert this code:

```
#define PROCEDURES\
    (procedureNameA, procedureIdA, procedureTypeA, procedureOutcomeA)\
    (procedureNameB, procedureIdB, procedureTypeB, procedureOutcomeB)\
    (procedureNameC, procedureIdC, procedureTypeC, procedureOutcomeC)\
    (procedureNameD, procedureIdD, procedureTypeD, procedureOutcomeD)
```

to this code fragment:

```
{ procedureIdA * 10 + procedureTypeA, "procedureNameA"},
{ procedureIdB * 10 + procedureTypeB, "procedureNameB"},
{ procedureIdC * 10 + procedureTypeC, "procedureNameC"},
{ procedureIdD * 10 + procedureTypeD, "procedureNameD"}
```

If so, how? I'm also open to non-Boost alternatives if it is easier. I'm also open to changing the way the list is defined to make the conversion possible.

Comment: There would be no benefit in using preprocessor here since you type all the names and ids.

Comment: @VTT since part of the information vanishes, I expect this to be only one of several uses of `PROCEDURES`.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe, but I doubt that preprocessor is required here at all.

Comment: Yes, i plan to use `PROCEDURES` elsewhere.